# SQl Server 2000 Execution: Statistics Missing

Tags: statistics, sql-server-2000, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a sitauation in production where a procedure is taking different time in two different envionments, when I tried to run the execution plan some stastics are missing. When I clicked on those icon(which was in red color for some attention). Stsstics are missing in both server. But I am wondering after seeing a message. There was a field called number of executes which was 23 in slow server and 1 in fast server. Can someone please tell the importance of this.

**Edit** Fragmentation is not a problem because when I checked I found Reorganizing would only relocate 2% of pages , New server was created with merge replication. Please advice on "number of executes" in execution lan and how we can work to reduce this.

**Edit:** will re building of indexes make any performance improvement

Comment: Can you guarantee that data, indexes, results, hardware, @@version and settings are **all** identical?

Comment: data, indexex, results and version is are same (SQL 2000). But new server which is slow is a named instance insatlled on SQl server 2003. but old server SQl server is inastlled on Windows 2000 OS.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2000 has had issues with statistics and some execution plans in the past, and you would have to add query hints in order to make sure the execution would happen the way you want it.  For starters, make sure you are on SP4, and then apply the following patch:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936232

This patch, while states an issue with an illegal operation (it resolves crashing with 64 bit machines and SQL2000), it also resolves a few other execution plan issues.  Though I would ultimately recommend upgrading to SQL 2008, which has seemed to resolve a number of statistic issues that we used to encounter.

Here is a link that explains in more detail the number of executes:

http://www.qdpma.com/CBO/ExecutionPlanCostModel.html

Comment: Ok, but I can't maka a major changes in production environment and we will be migrating to SQL Server 2008 soon. But I have doubt, if two stored procedure are same with same indexes and same data in table then execution plan should be almost same. why difference of 1 & 23 is coming. stored procedure is taking 4 sec for execution in fasexecution in fast server and 23 sec in slow server. slow server is one where I no of executes = 23. any idea what should be cross checked.

Comment: Make sure the statistics are updated on the slow server. In the sql analyzer, run "sp_updatestats". Does that change anything? You could also run "dbcc dbreindex(tablename)" to defragment an index. Just curious how did you get the database on the second server? Backup/restore or dts?

Comment: @@Brain: Please see the edited part of question. I have comleted all these stuff and I am only worried about "number of executes" in execution plan.

Comment: Ahhh.  Replication.  I believe there are triggers created on the published tables, which could be the extra processing that you are seeing.

Comment: @@Brain: once the replication is over how the trigger will impact on the execution of a stored procedure. It will impact only if I am having a trigger on the table which is used inside the stored procedure. morever I am using only a big seletc query inside the stored procedure pointing to 2 tables only. with some bussiness logic. So i think trigger should not be a problem. Please suggest if you think some where else something else to check.